# String inside structure behavior

Tags: c#, .net, string, pointers

Let's say we have structure

```
struct MyStruct
{
    public string a;
}
```

When we assign it to the new variable what will be happened with the string? So for example, we expect that string should be shared when structs are copied in the stack. We're using this code to test it, but it returns different pointers:

```
    var a = new MyStruct();
    a.a = "test";

    var b = a;

    IntPtr pA = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(a.a);
    IntPtr pB = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(b.a);

    Console.WriteLine("Pointer of a : {0}", (int)pA);
    Console.WriteLine("Pointer of b : {0}", (int)pB);
```

The question is when structs are copied in the stack and have string inside did it share the string or the string is recreated?

[UPDATE]

We also tried this code, it returns different pointers as well:

```
    char charA2 = a.a[0];
    char charB2 = b.a[0];

    unsafe
    {
        var pointerA2 = &charA2;
        var pointerB2 = &charB2;


        Console.WriteLine("POinter of a : {0}", (int)pointerA2);
        Console.WriteLine("Pointer of b : {0}", (int)pointerB2);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you use to test it 'Copies the contents of a managed String to a block of memory allocated from the unmanaged COM task allocator.' according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.stringtocotaskmemansi(v=vs.100).aspx). I would be surprised if any two subsequent calls to `StringToCoTaskMemAnsi` would return the same pointer. You can look at the memory address of the two string references or assign an object id using the debugger. Or easier: `object.ReferenceEquals(a.a, b.a);`

In your update, you are pointing to the stack location of the character variables, also not a good way of finding out. In any case, you are just copying the reference when you assign a string to another string, so they should always be the same.

Comment: "In any case, you are just copying the reference when you assign a string to another string, so they should always be the same", but it return different pointers in the output.

Comment: @JevgenijNekrasov the way you test it will **always** ensure different pointers, no matter the input. Look at the last sentence of my first paragraph in the answer, either do a check using `ReferenceEquals` or use the VS debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable in storage and a reference type. Furthermore in your example, the string "test" is [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). So no matter how many copies of the struct you makes you ultimately have multiple pointers to the same underling storage (unless you go through gyrations to copy it to a new block of memory which your contrived examples are doing)

Rest assured that there is only one copy, pointed at multiple times.